# React Testing Library asyncronous requests issue: fetch request undefined in tests

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm facing an issue while testing a React component that fetches data from an API. The API request works perfectly when executed in the browser, indicating that the API is functioning as expected. However, when running my test suite, the API request doesn't seem to execute, resulting in test failures.

The component I'm testing is a simple user list:

```
Users.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Users() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const getUsers = async () => {
            console.log('fetching users');
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
                const parsedResponse = await response.json();
                console.log('this is the response', parsedResponse);
                setUsers(parsedResponse);
            } catch (error) {
                setError('Error fetching users');
            }
        };
        getUsers();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Users</p>
            
                <ul>
                    {users.map((user) => (
                        <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            
            {error && <p>{error}</p>}
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is what I have tried to test the component :

```
Users.test.js
import { render, screen, fireEvent, act, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';

import Users from '../Users';


describe('tests Users component', ()=>{
    
    test('should render a list of users', async()=>{
        await act(async () => {
            render(<Users />);
          });
          await waitFor(() => {
            const ulElem = screen.getAllByRole('listitem');
            expect(ulElem).toHaveLength(10);
          })
    }) 
    test('CORS request to check for blocking', async () => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
            method: 'GET',
            mode : 'cors'
          });
          console.log('testing response',response)
          const data = await response.json();
          
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('CORS request error:', error);
        }
      });
      
    
})
```

What I expect from the the first test is that the list of users is rendered so the ulElem array stores 10 listitems.
For the second test, I expect to print to the console the same data that I obtained if I executed the request on the browser, which is a list of 10 users.
However, the results are not as expected:

In the first test, I receive an error: "Unable to find role='listitem'."
In the second test, I get "Testing response: undefined."
I'd appreciate guidance on identifying whether this is a CORS issue, a network problem, or an asynchronous delay, and how to resolve it for successful testing.